# Does the T1000 breathe?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Was watching T2 the other night and noticed that in the scene after Sarah, John and Uncle Bob flee from the psychiatric hospital and escape the T1000, when the T1000 returns to the hospital (the 'say, that's a nice bike' scene) the terminator appears to be exhaling warm breath into the cold night air. I know it is stated the the T800 has 'bad breath' but they have living tissue when the T1000 is liquid. Is it meant to be the case that the T1000 has false breath or just a slip by the fx dept?

Comment: I have no evidence for an answer, but logically speaking its design was intended to infiltrate human society my mimicry.  Any way in which it doesn’t look/feel/smell like a person is a risk to that mission.  Especially for the autonomic behaviors (ie it should be able to override defaults to NOT blend in, eg extending blade hands, but only when it specifically wants to)

Comment: in theory the T-1000 definitely COULD breathe it would simply be a case of producing a pocket of air inside it and then expanding and contracting it (though the breath probably wouldn't smell) and that breath probably would be warm due to the waste heat from all that living metal. If it actually did i wouldn't know

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I honestly think it is just a filming error and not anything to do with the T1000 blending skills.

Comment: Perhaps it's for mechanical cooling. It is a machine, after all.

Comment: Exactly, Paul. I doubt that the motorcyclist cop would immediately jump to the conclusion that a breathless T-1000 was a non-living artificial being, but I guess it's better to be safe than sorry.